# How to upload image to Firestore in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi how can I upload an image chosen from the gallery to Firestore ?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        image.makeRoundCorners(byRadius: 20)
        image.image = UIImage(named: ("upload")) //Default image
    }

    @IBAction func choose(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
           if let imageV = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
               image.image = imageV
        }
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

    @IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {


    }
}

extension UIImageView {

   func makeRoundCorners(byRadius rad: CGFloat) {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = rad
      self.clipsToBounds = true
   }
}
```

I want to upload it on Firestore so I will be able to retrieve the url of the image and then render it. With this code I'm able to let the user choose an image from his gallery but then how can I upload it when I press the upload button for example ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Best practice would be to upload to Firebase Storage and than just to have link stored in Firebase Firestore with some additional data. Was that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes this is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first import FirebaseFirestore.

```
import FirebaseFirestore
```

Then you can access the FireStore to first (1) upload the image to the store and afterwards (2) get the URL to access the image.

```
let metadata = StorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
storage.child("images").putData(imageV.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4), metadata: metadata) { meta, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    storage.child(folder).downloadURL { url, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle any errors
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

I like to have an extension of UIImage to do so:

```
extension UIImage {
    func upload(with folder: String, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        //let fileName = [UUID().uuidString, String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)].joined()
        let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        storage.child(folder).putData(data, metadata: metadata) { meta, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            storage.child(folder).downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil)
                }
                else {
                    completion(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like

```
imageV.upload(with: "images", completion: { (url: URL?) in
    print(url)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I've tried it and I got an error message saying that I don't have the permission ? Do you know why ? The message is  `" Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access"`

Comment: @SauceCurry Please check your authentication rules of your Storage. Fire base -> Develop -> Rules . Storage.storage().reference() should use the reference for your appropriate user.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks ! I have one more question please, how can I use the url to store it in database ?

Comment: @SauceCurry The above code includes the sample how to download the data (storage.child(folder).downloadURL. If your question refers to how to store the data locally on the device, please open a new question, as this is another topic.

Comment: Yeah but I can't store it in my database because it's a void function and I need it in a String format

Comment: @SauceCurry It is an optional URL callback. Calling this method should give you the URL where you can access this image on the FireStore... You can either download it (after uploading it) or store the url